# insert and update sql queries with php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I would like to insert identifiers in my database each time using in a php page using ajax, I have a submit button for the insert and another for the update:

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="boutonR" id="insert_button" name="insert">Insérer</button>
    <button type="submit" class="boutonR" id="update_button" name="update">Mettre à jour</button>
    <button type="submit" class="boutonR" id="delete_button" name="delete">Supprimer</button>
</div>
```

and this is the ajax part:

```
$("#insert_button").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault ();

    var form_url = $(".form_con").attr("action");
    var form_method = $(".form_con").attr("method");
    var form_data = $(".form_con").serialize (); // encoder les élements du formulaire pour la soumission.

    $.ajax ({
        url : form_url,
        type: form_method,
        data: form_data
    }).done (function (response) {
        //$("#resRecherche").html(response);
        alert("Success !");
    });
});
```

And here is the script:

```
<?php

include 'connect_pdo.php';

ini_set("display_errors", "1");

error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include ("connect_pdo.php");

    header('Content-type: text/html');

    $reg = $_GET['idTombe'];

    if (isset($reg)) {
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

            if (isset($_POST['nom_concessionnaire']) && isset($_POST['num_concession'])) {

                     $sql_update = "update concessionnaire set num_concession = ?, nom_concessionnaire = ? where id_concessionnaire=?";
                     $stmt = $bdd -> prepare ($sql_update);
                     $stmt -> execute ($_POST['num_concession'], $_POST['nom_concessionnaire'], $reg);

            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['insert'])) { // if button insert is set
            if (isset($_POST['nom_concessionnaire']) && isset($_POST['num_concession'])) {

                    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO possede (id_concessionnaire, id_concession) VALUES (?,?)";
                    $stmt_i = $bdd -> prepare ($sql_insert);
                    $stmt_i -> execute ([$row['id_concessionnaire'], $row['id_concession']]);

            }
        }

    }//end isset
```

This does not work, it redirects me to the homepage and does not insert the data in the database, I don't know if it is my ajax code or my php script.
Thank you

Comment: I forgot to post my form header
<form role="form" method="post" action="update_insert.php" class="form_con">

Comment: You can edit your question if you need to complete it, you don't need to put things out of context in the comments. The "edit" button is at the bottom of your question under the blue tags

Comment: Anyway it's unclear, it's possible the button click event may not be bound to the button properly - is the jQuery code within a document.ready block?

Comment: If your form action is `update_insert.php` your `$_GET['idTombe']` will not be set and nothing will be executed

Comment: Why `include 'connect_pdo.php';` twice?

Comment: @ADyson I didn't know I could edit my question, I will edit it. Yes the JQuery code is within a document.ready block.

Comment: @brombeer You are right I put a var_dump on the $_GET and I get a NULL, the thing is that I need to get the ID of an area where I click on
It was a mistake from me the include twice

Comment: Just so you know, the ability to edit is mentioned in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to take when you signed up for the site (but I can see due to the lack of the relevant badge in your profile that you didn't do) - such resources exist to help you have a good experience on stackoverflow, so please use them - thanks :-) . And please also carry out the edit and include the form tag in the question :-)

Comment: Anyway brombeer is right, is your form sends a POST request to a URL which does not have a querystring then GET variables will not be populated in PHP when the form is submitted. If you want some value to be included when you submit the form, put it in a form field within the form (even if it's a hidden field the user cannot see).

Comment: Either use a hidden field with the ID and use `$_POST['idTombe']` or set the action to `update_insert.php?idTombe=XYZ`

Comment: @ADyson thank you, I will :)

Comment: @brombeer ah ok I see thank you